# Killing application Picasso reloads the images everywhere in application in android

Tags: java, android, caching, picasso, image-loading

I've implemented Picasso library for loading the images. Image Caching is working perfectly until we kills the application. If application gets killed Picasso loads images again, no caching. This is a well known bug in this library as I've read it in various blogs, somewhere I read that updating the Picasso library resolves this issue, I did the same but it is still remaining. Right now I am using Picasso Version2.5.2. If anybody has a nice experience with Picasso please let me know a few things.

What is the most updated version of the Picasso?
Is this issue still remaining in Picasso in latest version?
is there tricky solution for this?
Which library i need to use for overcoming this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: my suggestion is to use [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Answer (score 1):

For loading images after killed app, you should follow instructions:

1. Server should return image with header `Cache-Control`
   i.e. `Cache-Control:public, max-age=604800` 
   more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control
2. You should create own picasso instance: 
   `Cache cache = new Cache(context.getCacheDir(), 30000000); 
   OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().cache(cache).build(); 
   OkHttp3Downloader downloader = new OkHttp3Downloader(client); 
   Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(appContext).downloader(downloader).build();`
3. Load image: `picasso.load(url).into(imageView);`

Explaination:

> Picasso doesn't have a disk cache. It delegates to whatever HTTP client you are using for that functionality (relying on HTTP cache semantics for cache control). Because of this, the behavior you seek comes for free

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented Picasso to force it to look for cache records first before fetching the images online again..Due note that the library has a 65MB cache limit..read that somewhere in the documentation

```
 Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(Link)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.grad)
                    .error(R.drawable.grad)
                    .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                    .fit()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(image, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            //successfully loads from CACHE
                            image.setClickable(true);
                            ..............
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            // fetch online because cache is not there
                            Picasso.with(context)
                                    .load(Link)
                                    .fetch(new Callback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess() {
                                            Picasso.with(context)
                                                    .load(Link)
                                                    .fit()
                                                    .centerCrop()
                                                    .into(image, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onSuccess() {

                                                        //success..
                                                        }

                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onError() {
                                                            Toast.makeText(context, "No Image Found. Try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                            image.setClickable(false);

                                                        }
                                                    });
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onError() {
                                            //NO IMAGE offline or online
                                            Toast.makeText(context, "No Image Found. Try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            image.setClickable(false);

                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    });
```